# Using memoizing selectors with Hooks in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, memoization, reselect

One of the components in my react native app is re-rendering several times causing problems with my derived data.
I'm using **Redux** to store my state and **useSelector** hook to retrieve the state and use it during rendering. I've read quite a bit about the use of Reselect library to avoid unnecessary rendering and optimise performance but I'm struggling to apply to my ES6 code with hooks.

This is my current code

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import...

const MovieDetailScreen = (props) => {
  const selectedMovie = useSelector((state) => state.moviemain.moviemain);
  const selectedMovieCast = useSelector((state) => state.moviecast.moviecast);
  const selectedMovieCrew = useSelector((state) => state.moviecast.moviecrew);

  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <View>
        <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={3}>
           {selectedMovie.name}
        </Text>            
     </View>
     <View>
        <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={3}>
           {selectedMovie.overview}
        </Text>            
     </View>
     <View>
        <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={3}>
           {selectedMovie.released_date}
        </Text>            
     </View>
     <View style={styles.textLabelRow}>
         {selectedMovie.genres.map((item, id) => {
           return (
              <Text
                 style={[styles.txtLabel, { backgroundColor: "#404040" }]}
                 key={id}
                 numberOfLines={1}
              >
                 {item.name}
              </Text>
           );
         })}
     </View>
   </View>
   ...
   ...
  );
};
```

I would like to apply the Reselect to any derived data, in the example code attached it would be the mapping processing of the genres parameter of the selectedMovie state

```
         {selectedMovie.genres.map((item, id) => {
           return (
              <Text
                 style={[styles.txtLabel, { backgroundColor: "#404040" }]}
                 key={id}
                 numberOfLines={1}
              >
                 {item.name}
              </Text>
           );
         })}
```

I have another dozens of similar scenarios where I need to filter data or work out totals and due to re-rendering I often get errors.
I believe that using Reselect, the function would only be executed if the state changes.

I tried to follow the example in [here](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector) by moving my state selection outside my component and restructure my code like this

```
import...
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

const getMovie = createSelector(
  (state) => state.moviemain.moviemain,
  (moviemain) => moviemain.moviemain.map((item) => item.genres)
);

export const GenresList = () => {
  const genres = useSelector(getMovie);
  return (
    <Text
      style={[styles.txtLabel, { backgroundColor: "#404040" }]}
      numberOfLines={1}
    >
      {genres}
    </Text>
  );
};

const MovieDetailScreen = (props) => {
  const selectedMovie = useSelector((state) => state.moviemain.moviemain);
  const selectedMovieCast = useSelector((state) => state.moviecast.moviecast);
  const selectedMovieCrew = useSelector((state) => state.moviecast.moviecrew);

  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     ....
     ....
     <View>
        <GenresList />            
     </View>
   </View>
   ...
   ...
  );
};
```

but I'm getting the following error in the createSelector function
***undefined is not an object (evaluating 'moviemain.moviemain.map')***

I've tried other suggested solutions having all code within the main components but I get other types of errors.

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**;
In the following code the first argument returns the moviemian.moviemain property, and the next line you want to get the moviemain property of that - meaning: moviemian.moviemain.moviemain which is undefined so you cant map it.

```js
const getMovie = createSelector(
  (state) => state.moviemain.moviemain,
  (moviemain) => moviemain.moviemain.map((item) => item.genres)
);
```

**Remember**: what you write in a selector you get the result in the second argument.

**Solution**: remove the extra moviemain:

```js
(moviemain) => moviemain.map((item) => item.genres)
```

Redux selectors can be tricky, here's a refresher

```js
// you can either use multiple selectors
// declare these outside of component 
const getSelectedMovie = (state) => state.moviemain.moviemain;
const getSelectedMovieCast = (state) => state.moviecast.moviecast;
const getSelectedMovieCrew = (state) => state.moviecast.moviecrew;

// or use one since its the same object
const getSelectedMovieAll = (state) => state.moviemain;

// so that you can use them inside component like

const MovieDetailScreen = (props) => {
    const selectedMovie = useSelector(getSelectedMovie);
    const movies = useSelector(getSelectedMovieAll);

    // pay attention to the keys, they remain the same
    const { moviecast: selectedMovieCast, moviecrew: selectedMovieCrew } = movies;

}
```

Well, that's for the redux part, about reselect, you can use it like this:

```js
const example = createSelector(
  [selector1, selector2]
  (resultOfSelector1, resultOfSelector2) => ({ 'return': 'something'})
);

// so in case moviemain.moviemain is an array you can do the following
// make sure you reuse the previous selectors
const getMovie = createSelector(
  [getSelectedMovie]
  (moviemain) => moviemain.map((item) => item.genres)
);

export const GenresList = () => {
  const genres = useSelector(getMovie);
  return (
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, the first part of your solution (Redux) worked, in fact I now declare the state outside the component and refer the useSelector from within the component and all data are refreshed correctly!

Comment: As for the second part, I'm still getting the error  In **'moviemain.map(function (item) { return item.genres; })', 'moviemain.map' is undefined)**  Code outside component is:  `const getSelectedMovie = (state) => state.moviemain.moviemain;
const getMovie = createSelector([getSelectedMovie], (moviemain) =>
  moviemain.map((item) => item.genres)
);
export const GenresList = () => {
  const genres = useSelector(getMovie);
  return (
    <Text>{genres}</Text>
  );
}; `

Comment: well, it depends on what you store inside state.moviemain. I'm not sure what your final goal is, if you have an array of movies from which you want to extract only the genres then this should be correct.

console.log(state.moviemain);
console.log(typeof state.moviemain); 
 this should tell you what is the content, if its not an array this wont work

Comment: Inside the component I'm using  `{selectedMovie.genres.map((item, id) => {
                return ( <Text key={id}> {item.name} </Text> ); })} `  and it's working fine. If I follow your solution outside the component with the use of createSelector I get the problem.  In state.moviemain.moviemain the first moviemain is the reducer reference and the second moviemain is the actual state property in the reducer that hold the data, hope it helps.

Comment: Finally got it working. My bad, I should have used (moviemain) => moviemain.genres.map((item) => item.genres) instead of (moviemain) => moviemain.map((item) => item.genres). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help